# KeyError: Spider not found [Scrapy]

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I had two spiders, both had same name (to err is human).

```
class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Product'
```

When I crawled, both spiders crawled.

So, when I changed the name of one of the spiders (the other spider still had the same name `Product`):

```
scrapy crawl Product
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 150, in crawl
    crawler = self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 165, in _create_crawler
    spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 40, in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: Product'
```

However, while debugging, when I changed the name `Product` to a random new fresh name, `foo`, it worked.

I don't get it. Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure both spiders were syntactically valid and could be imported at the moment?

Comment: Yes, they were syntactically valid. In fact, working as expected, initially, with same names.

Comment: What about the case - both spiders were named `Product` and not `product` and `Product`?

Comment: Can you reproduce this strange behavior?

Comment: As far as I am aware, scrapy can only crawl one spider even if the spider has a duplicate name. This is proven in the source as these names are stored within a dict `{}` and not `defaultdict`, so we won't bet a list of class for each name. Therefore, your case would be impossible.